# "New query window" shortcut for Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sql-developer, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm used to Ctrl-N to give me a new query window in SSMS. How do I do it in Oracle?

Comment: From tool bar click sql icon or Alt+F10

Comment: [This](https://shortcutworld.com/Oracle-SQL-Developer/win/Oracle-SQL-Developer_4_Shortcuts) might interest you. Check out the articles in my profile on how to ask questions on this site!

Comment: Alt-F10 does nothing for me in SQL Developer 1.5.5.  Instead I have to right mouse on the connection name and click "Open SQL Worksheet".

Answer (score 18):

In Oracle SQL Developer Application

Goto: `Tools->SQL Worksheet`

OR

```
ALT+F10
```